# C++ - a "private" singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton, encapsulation

In C++, I would normally implement a singleton in the following manner:

```
class singleton
{
public:
    static singleton& get_instance();

private:
    singleton(){};
    singleton(singleton const&);
    singleton operator=(singleton const&);
}
```

Currently, I'm building a large library which relies on a finite state machine, and I don't want to be passing a pointer to it to almost every single class instance for the purposes of code cleanliness. Therefore, I have decided to wrap it in a singleton.

There is a problem however: the end user of the library should not be allowed access to this singleton. Exposing it could allow the user to break the internal functionality of the library.

Now, I could make `get_instance` private and declare the relevant internal classes as a friend, but that would allow for violation of the singleton principle within the library code itself, as instantion would no longer be restricted from its point of view. Is there any clever way of fulfilling the requirement of having a singleton which can only be accessed from a part of the codebase?

Comment: `friend singleton& get_singleton_instance()` function inside `mylib::internal` namespace

Comment: Why not simply... Not expose the singleton header in the end-user library?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but I'm not sure it's the best solution or even viable for you.

Many problems can be resolved by an extra layer and that's what I'm proposing here: you can use an [**opaque pointer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) (aka pimpl idiom) to your singleton, so this extra layer is the public interface to the singleton and is the only friend of the singleton and thus can do the violation, but it is one simple class working together with the singleton.

The opaque pointer duplicates all public functions and these are called by the library classes that are friends of the opaque pointer. The functions just forward to the singleton via the get_access() call.

This way, no user code can access the opaque pointer or singleton, the library classes use the opaque pointer and even though they are friends of the opaque pointer, they can't use the that to access the singleton and the opaque pointer could violate the singleton principle, but in fact, it is a small class working closely with the singleton.

To the library classes, it would look like the don't work with a singleton but with a class that they all can instantiate separately and call functions on it.